# View source code for builtin emacs package

Tags: emacs

How can I view source code for a builtin Emacs package?
For instance given lisp code `(require 'color)`, I would be interested in which functions are provided by that package. I googled `emacs "color.el"` and found the source code. But I wonder if this file can be viewed directly from within Emacs itself? By the way, `find . -name 'color*'` gives

```
./share/emacs/24.3/lisp/color.el.gz
./share/emacs/24.3/lisp/color.elc
```

Comment: Because I dig into the source code on a daily basis, I keep an uncompressed original source on my desktop for all computers so that I can easily search it and open the files.  See the links underneath `Obtaining/Downloading GNU Emacs`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/   The added benefit is that I'm not damaging my working copy by accidentally modifying the source.  The `C-h f` tells me which file is at issue, assuming I know the name of the function.  I'm always word-searching the files in the `lisp` folder . . . and sometimes the root when it may be written in C to understand the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either open the file directly in Emacs. I think `.gz` files are by default decompressed. Usually, I pick out one function from the package I'm interested in (e.g. `org-mode`), look up the documentation for that using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `org-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> and then click on the file name in the documentation buffer. It will take you the source file.

Comment: `C-h f` seems not to work.. I type `color-mode` and press enter but I get no match

Comment: I don't think `color-mode` is a function. You need to find some actual function in the package.

Answer (score 14):

You can get to the source code in a single command with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library`.

Answer (score 4):

So `./share/emacs/24.3/lisp/color.el.gz` is the gzipped source code, and you can open that in emacs by first doing `M-x auto-compression-mode`, and then visiting that file.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Is there a way to do this without knowing the exact path to the file?